# JavaFX - Change image URL

Tags: javafx

as a school project I'm working on a small JavaFX text adventure. Because I'd rather not have a billion Images sitting around, I've been trying to find out how I can change the URL value of an Image so as to save valuable ram. I don't seem to be able to find anything, however. Does anyone know how to change an Image's URL?
IDE: Eclipse Oxygen + e(fx)clipse

Comment: read the api doc? search (this site, your favorite search engine, tutorials, your course doc ... ) for similar questions?

Comment: Tried for about half an hour, found nothing relevant. Api docs confuse me still, not very advanced of a programmer and they use a lot of confusing terms I don't understand yet. I'm a student at a school that decided ''You know that end of term project theyre supposed to do? Let's make it about javafx, about which these people know basically nothing, and then make a maths teacher the only other person in the room.'' Can't ask anything but stackoverflow at this point.

Comment: You can't change an image's URL (it might not even have a URL, e.g. for a `WritableImage`). It sounds like you're worrying about issues that probably don't exist; if an image goes out of scope, it is eligible for garbage collection like any other object.

Comment: you will not get an answer most probably, because the question isn't clear enough. And you wont get anywhere by starting your code at the top (like thinking about optimization) Instead start at the bottom and ask concrete questions when you get stuck (and don't forget to read up about how to ask questions on this site!)